# Convert Apex application from 19.2 to 19.1?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an Apex application on a server running Apex 19.2

I would like to import this application into a server running Apex 19.1

The import doesn't work saying that the versions are not compatible.

I tried to manully change the release date in the application sql file to "fake" the version but it still doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Thanks.
Cheers,

Comment: If the app uses *any* [new features in 19.2](https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/oracle-apex-192-early-adopter-now-available), then it should *not* work in 19.1 no matter what you do, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not only the release **date**, but **release** itself:

```
wwv_flow_api.import_begin (
  p_version_yyyy_mm_dd => '2020.02.24',
  p_release            => '19.1.x.yy.zz'     --> this
  ...
```

Did you do that as well?

Perhaps you'll be interested in reading [How to import an Oracle APEX Application export file from a higher version into a lower version](https://www.triology.de/en/blog-entries/database-applications-import-oracle-apex). There's no guarantee that it'll actually work, but - if you're desperate enough, try it.